# keeping a button active while switching between pages

Tags: javascript, html, button, switching, multipage

I am making a multi pager for a school project, it has all been going pretty well till now, but there is one thing i can't figure out,
i have a small java script that changes between 2 CSS files when clicked on a switch button, the one CSS`` page is a dark mode of the other CSS page.
so the button works, but every time i switch from the page i am on to another page the button resets, so for example if I'm om the home page and turn dark mode on, and then go to gallery page for example the dark mode resets and goes back to light, i wonder if anyone knows what i have to add to my java script to make this work properly.
thanks in advance.

```js
document.getElementById('myonoffswitch').onclick = function() {
    console.log('123')
    if (document.getElementById('myonoffswitch').checked) {
      document.getElementById('theme').href = "../css/dark.css";
    } else {
      document.getElementById('theme').href = "../css/style.css";
    };
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  height: 45px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 23px;
  text-align: center;
}

.hover {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.hover::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  transition: transform 0.25s ease-out;
}

.hover:hover::before {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}

.header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 98%;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

footer {
  background-image: radial-gradient(#000000, #535252);
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  box-shadow: rgb(0, 0, 0) 2px 2px 2px;
  margin-top: auto;
}

center {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
}

.onoffswitch {
  position: relative;
  width: 90px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.onoffswitch-label {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.onoffswitch-inner {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  margin-left: -100%;
  transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before,
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before {
  content: "ON";
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:after {
  content: "OFF";
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  color: #999999;
  text-align: right;
}

.onoffswitch-switch {
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  margin: 6px;
  background: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 56px;
  border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked+.onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked+.onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
  right: 0px;
}

.box {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  width: 800px;
  border: 5px solid rgb(211, 211, 211);
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 10px;
  height: 452px;
  word-spacing: 5px;
}

.headline {
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.moviecenter {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}

.resp-iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  left: 1100px;
  width: 912px;
  height: 561px;
  border: 0;
}

#content {
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: abel;
  background-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  color: #ffffff8a;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 7px 0px #8585858a;
  text-align: center;
}

#imageTable {
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.gallery {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 5px solid #000000;
  width: 1000px;
}

#container {
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.desc {
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery:hover {
  border: 5px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="openings pagina van onze portofilio website" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="portofilio, animatie, beeld, geluid, video, internettechnieken, scripten, grafische, vormgeving" />
  <meta name="author" content="Liam De Herdt" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Home</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../images/heylen.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" id="theme">
  <link href="../css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="../js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/lightbox.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

  <div class="headline">
    <h1 style="font-family: 'Spray.ME'; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal;">S.I.T Secure Inmates Transport</h1>
  </div>

  <nav class="header">
    <ul>
      <li class="hover"><a href="../Home/index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li class="hover"><a href="../Info/info.html">Info</a></li>
      <li class="hover"><a href="../Gallery/gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
      <li class="hover"><a href="../Story/story.html">Story</a></li>
      <li class="hover"><a href="../Contact/contact.html">Contact</a></li>

    </ul>
  </nav>



  <div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" tabindex="0">
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">

      <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
      <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>

    </label>
  </div>



  <script src="../js/dark.js"></script>

  <div class="box">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut a vulputate orci, non posuere metus. Suspendisse potenti. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Duis scelerisque nibh massa. Sed tempus
      nunc libero, sed dictum tortor facilisis et. Donec dictum, dolor et tristique scelerisque, enim justo vestibulum eros, sed fringilla purus purus non mauris. Nulla vitae neque tortor. Nullam scelerisque faucibus commodo. Donec tincidunt elementum
      nibh ac laoreet. Pellentesque velit odio, eleifend et eros sed, faucibus gravida lorem. Donec vulputate dui ut nibh dictum, ut egestas ante mollis. Suspendisse suscipit tellus urna, id posuere nunc lobortis vel. Pellentesque maximus fringilla augue,
      in tincidunt orci vulputate in. Cras ut dapibus augue, sit amet convallis enim. Donec sollicitudin enim lacinia, bibendum felis vitae, efficitur nisl. Sed scelerisque tellus orci, quis commodo dolor elementum eget. Vestibulum blandit lobortis nisi,
      et hendrerit ipsum tincidunt quis. Ut dapibus mi facilisis est tristique suscipit. Suspendisse suscipit tellus urna, id posuere nunc lobortis vel. Pellentesque maximus fringilla augue, in tincidunt orci vulputate in. Cras ut dapibus augue, sit amet
      convallis enim. Donec sollicitudin enim lacinia, bibendum felis vitae, efficitur nisl. Sed scelerisque tellus orci, quis commodo dolor elementum eget. Vestibulum blandit lobortis nisi, et hendrerit ipsum tincidunt quis. Ut dapibus mi facilisis est
      tristique suscipit.Suspendisse suscipit tellus urna, id posuere nunc lobortis vel. Pellentesque maximus fringilla augue, in tincidunt
    </h1>

  </div>

  <div id="moviecenter">
    <iframe class="resp-iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8LfWdV944kU" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>



  <div id="container">
    <div id="content">
      <br>
      <table id="imageTable">
        <tr>
          <td class="gallery">
            <a target="_blank" href="../images/Liam_Digitale_fotomontage_definite.jpg" data-lightbox="goeienavond">
              <img src="../images/Liam_Digitale_fotomontage_definite.jpg" alt="textImg" width="400" height="600">
            </a>
            <div class="desc">Digitale Foto Montage</div>
          </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="gallery">
            <a target="_blank" href="../images/technisch_plan_Liam.jpg" data-lightbox="goeienavond">
              <img src="../images/technisch_plan_Liam.jpg" alt="textImg" width="400" height="600">
            </a>
            <div class="desc">Technisch Plan</div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>







  </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
  </div>





  <footer>
    <p class="pfooter">&copy; Liam De Herdt 2020 </p>
  </footer>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: localStorage can be your friend;)

Answer (score 1):

What about javascript's local storage? You could set a value in one page and then retrieve in in the next page. This could be what you see below or the state of your button represented as a string. You could then use this string to set the style of your button to enabled or disable.

[Local Storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

```js
// Store enabled value
localStorage.setItem("myButtonState", "enabled");
// Or, Store disabled value
// localStorage.setItem("myButtonState", "disabled");
    
// Retrieve value
var myButtonState = localStorage.getItem("myButtonState");

// Check value if enabled
if(myButtonState == "enabled") {
  document.getElementById("myButtonState").disabled = false;
}

// Check value if disabled
if(myButtonState == "disabled") {
  document.getElementById("myButtonState").disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="myButton" disabled="">Button1</button>
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to coding, and i don't quite understand what you mean ^-^'

Comment: No problem. I have created an example for you to check out. For security reasons it will not work on here but it will on your computer. Local Storage is like a cache. Remember that It will be cleared when you clear you cache and cookies.

Comment: i'll check it out in a bit, thank you, i'll, let you know if it works

Comment: i see where you re going, the only problem now is that i'm not using <button>, but this

Comment: <div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" tabindex="0">
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">

      <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
      <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>

    </label>
  </div>

Comment: i dont know how to add another id and type to it

Comment: a second type i obviously cant add, but i supose i can just use the type i haveright now, but i'm not sure if a second id woill work, ill check